# Warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments. Any ideas?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, nsstring

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSArray *listData =[self.tableContents objectForKey:
                    [self.sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *rowValue = [listData objectAtIndex:row];

NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:rowValue];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"You Better Be There Or Be Watching It!"
                      message:message delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Go Knights!"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[message release];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}


Line of code that throws error: 
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:rowValue];
----------
 Warning Message: format not a string literal and no format arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

The `stringWithFormat:` method takes a string format with `n` arguments. For your needs, just use:

```
NSString *message = rowValue;
```

According to your code example, you don't need to allocate memory for the string object or provide a certain format.